# IIS 6 on W 2003 extension less mvc settings (The page cannot be found)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, configuration, iis-6

Couple questions

1. Asp.net version is not displayed in properties of website in ASP.NET tab in IIS6 (the drop down list is empty), why is that?
2. Is there anything I am missing in my mvc enabling process

I get error: The page cannot be found when i am trying to access a page on an mvc website.

I have followed this guide: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Steps I have done, so far
this relate to : IIS 6 and w2k3

1. Select Website, right button -> properties
2. Home Directory, i have checked that read is checked and execute permitions are to script only
3. configuration-> Mappings
4. found aspx extension -> limit verbs to :GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG, Script engine is checked, verify that file exists is unchecked
5. Added .mvc extension with settings same as for aspx
6. OK

Comment: There is a wildcard setting there, which you should set in order to get it to work. Set the wildcard to the .NET isapi filter should do it.

Comment: that has done it, been blind to see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mike,
I have been blind beetle for not seing it

Wildcard application hast to be set to: same file as .mvc configuration

As to the registration,
 thank you Darin, i will try it today.

Thank you all

Comment: Where is this Wildcard application?

Comment: Where is this Wildcard application? -- Nevermind, I found it.  Right click on the application or website, Virtual Directory Tab, Click on Configuration, on the mappings tab find the .MVC extention, Wildcard application maps is the text area under the application extentions list box.  I went into detail in case someone else is missing it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try registering ASP.NET with IIS:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regsql.exe -i
```

Then make sure it is enabled:

[image]

If you are using ASP.NET 4.0 make sure you adapt those steps to the corresponding version.

Comment: I believe the correct file is aspnet_regiis.exe rather than aspnet_regsql.exe